# convert Lasagne to Keras code (CNN -> LSTM)

Tags: python, keras, lstm, lasagne

I would like to convert this Lasagne code:

```
et = {}
net['input'] = lasagne.layers.InputLayer((100, 1, 24, 113))
net['conv1/5x1'] = lasagne.layers.Conv2DLayer(net['input'], 64, (5, 1))
net['shuff'] = lasagne.layers.DimshuffleLayer(net['conv1/5x1'], (0, 2, 1, 3))
net['lstm1'] = lasagne.layers.LSTMLayer(net['shuff'], 128)
```

in Keras code. Currently I came up with this:

```
multi_input = Input(shape=(1, 24, 113), name='multi_input')
y = Conv2D(64, (5, 1), activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(multi_input)
y = LSTM(128)(y)
```

But I get the error: `Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`

Comment: That is the batch size, I am no expert of Lasagne but I think it is irrelevant whether to use it or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, LSTM, Permute, Reshape

multi_input = Input(shape=(1, 24, 113), name='multi_input')
print(multi_input.shape)  # (?, 1, 24, 113)

y = Conv2D(64, (5, 1), activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(multi_input)
print(y.shape)  # (?, 64, 20, 113)

y = Permute((2, 1, 3))(y)
print(y.shape)  # (?, 20, 64, 113)

# This line is what you missed
# ==================================================================
y = Reshape((int(y.shape[1]), int(y.shape[2]) * int(y.shape[3])))(y)
# ==================================================================
print(y.shape)  # (?, 20, 7232)

y = LSTM(128)(y)
print(y.shape)  # (?, 128)
```

## Explanations

I put the documents of Lasagne and Keras here so you can do cross-referencing:

[**Lasagne**](https://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers/recurrent.html)

> Recurrent layers can be used similarly to feed-forward layers except
>   that the input shape is expected to be `(batch_size, sequence_length, num_inputs)`

[**Keras**](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/)

> **Input shape**
>
> 3D tensor with shape `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`.

---

Basically the API is the same, but Lasagne probably does reshape for you (I need to check the source code later). That's why you got this error:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

, since the tensor shape after `Conv2D` is `(?, 64, 20, 113)` of `ndim=4`

Therefore, the solution is to reshape it to `(?, 20, 7232)`.

### Edit

Confirmed with the Lasagne [source code](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/lasagne/layers/recurrent.py#L863), it does the trick for you:

```
num_inputs = np.prod(input_shape[2:])
```

So the correct tensor shape as input for LSTM is `(?, 20, 64 * 113)` = `(?, 20, 7232)`

---

### Note

`Permute` is redundant here in Keras since you have to reshape anyway. The reason why I put it here is to have a "full translation" from Lasagne to Keras, and it does what `DimshuffleLaye` does in Lasagne.

`DimshuffleLaye` is however needed in Lasagne because of the reason I mentioned in **Edit**, the new dimension created by Lasagne LSTM is from the multiplication of "the last two" dimensions.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the solution and answer I was looking for.

Comment: Hi, here my question is related to this question. Here is the detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852767/need-to-convert-lasagne-to-keras-code-cnnlstm. Can you please answer this?